# How to resolve IndexOutOfBounds exception when using matcher.find()?

Tags: android, arrays, regex, list

My app suddenly stops if no match is found. This is the piece of code:

```
while (matcher.find()) {

  tagValues.add(matcher.group(1));


 }
```

How can I show the user there is no match and still be on the same page?
This is the logcat. It gives IndexOutOfBounds exception.

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
04-16 21:17:56.700: E/AndroidRuntime(19492):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
04-16 21:17:56.700: E/AndroidRuntime(19492):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
04-16 21:17:56.700: E/AndroidRuntime(19492):    at com.approve.smsapp.Conversation$1.onItemClick(Conversation.java:115)
04-16 21:17:56.700: E/AndroidRuntime(19492):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
04-16 21:17:56.700: E/AndroidRuntime(19492):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
04-16 21:17:56.700: E/AndroidRuntime(19492):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2904)
04-16 21:17:56.700: E/AndroidRuntime(19492):    at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3638)
```

Comment: Add more of your code and format it appropriately.

Comment: post your matcher arraylist code; you cannot do matcher.find or matcher.group if there is nothing in the arraylist or it is not initialized.

Answer (score 1):

please add more code to better understand your problem. see below a simple example of matcher, may be this will help you:

```
public class RegexTestPatternMatcher {
  public static final String EXAMPLE_TEST = "This is my small example string which I'm going to use for pattern matching.";

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w+");
    // in case you would like to ignore case sensitivity,
    // you could use this statement:
    // Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s+", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(EXAMPLE_TEST);
    // check all occurance
    while (matcher.find()) {
      System.out.print("Start index: " + matcher.start());
      System.out.print(" End index: " + matcher.end() + " ");
      System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
    // now create a new pattern and matcher to replace whitespace with tabs
    Pattern replace = Pattern.compile("\\s+");
    Matcher matcher2 = replace.matcher(EXAMPLE_TEST);
    System.out.println(matcher2.replaceAll("\t"));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the `matcher.group(1)` but your regex is not capturing the group one. So either change the `group(1)` into `group(0)` or capture the appropriate groups.

Here is an example that raises the `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException` exception.

```
String input = "some input";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".+");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

And the solution for above case is,

Either using group capture in regex:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.+)");
                                   ^  ^  group capture added.
```

Or using appropriate group, for example using `group(0)` in this case

```
System.out.println(m.group(0));
```